# undefined method `paypal_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am developing payment system in my app.for this i am taking reference of railcasts ep-141
i follow all steps as per episode but i got this error as

```
undefined method `paypal_url'
```

i tried so but not find out answer.

here i have BookingDetail maodel as follow

```
class BookingDetail < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :room
attr_accessible :member_type_id, :room_type_id, :start_date, :end_date, :room_rate_id, :room_no, :customer_id, :room_id


def total_price
room_type.to_a.sum(&:room_rate)
end


def paypal_url(return_url)
    values = {
      :business => '',
      :cmd => '_cart',
      :upload => 1,
      :return => return_url,
      :invoice => id
    }
    room_type.each_with_index do |item, index|
      values.merge!({
    "room_rate_#{index+1}" => item.room_rate,
    "room_type_#{index+1}" => item.room_type,
    "room_id_#{index+1}" => item.room_rate.room_id,
    "quantity_#{index+1}" => item.quantity
      })
    end
    "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

end

this line gives me error

```
  <%=link_to "Checkout",@room.paypal_url(rooms_url)%>
```

what did i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paypal_url` is not a method of `Room` as I see its a method of `BookingDetail` so you need to do the following

```
@room.booking_detail.paypal_url(rooms_url)
```

instead of

```
@room.paypal_url(rooms_url)
```

Assuming you have the following in `Room` Model

has_one :booking_detail

again the answer depends on what you have inside your `Room` model

Comment: this is done. but this is for has_one :booking_detail but in my model i have has_many :booking_details then what should i write

Comment: then it depends on which of the many booking_details you want to have the link